# How do I install the Eclipse Android ADP

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have installed the Android SDK and Eclipse. Now, I believe I need to connect them together with the ADT plugin.

I've read this...
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing1.2.3.4.-6.7.8.9.10.

but unless I've gone blind I cant see anywhere where it says how to install the ADT plugin.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep, you got blind.

At the right there is a link about **Installing the Eclipse Plugin** http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt realised that the thats what they meant by the ellipse plugin

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link on the same page

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html